# Are there any sites where I can submit a brief for a website?

Tags: contract, hiring

I work for a company that wants to redesign its website, and I've been asked to find a firm to do this. I've searched online and there are too many agencies! Are there any websites where companies can post a brief of what they want done, and agencies can read through and contact the company directly if the brief is of interest? If it makes any difference we're based in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elance](http://www.elance.com/)

Comment: Hello John, thank you for the link. I've not heard of Elance before. It seems to be for hiring individuals rather than a company. We're really looking for a company that will accept a brief and handle everything including project management, development, and artwork. Do you know if Elance is appropriate for that sort of thing? Thanks again.

Comment: If you put that in your brief then you'll attract companies who do that sort of thing. Elance is pretty much where anyone, whether a solo contractor or company, hang out looking for work.

Answer (score 3):

[Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com)

Pretty much the same thing. I would recommend posting on both sites as to attract the most amount of potential contracting companies.

Answer (score 0):

[oDesk](http://www.odesk.com)? I think you can hire teams on this.